# List View in SwiftUI is showing a grey area above the list which I can't get rid of

Tags: swiftui

I am not gonna lie, but the modifiers in SwiftUI are super tricky. I want to get rid of the grey area above my list. I have tried all, padding, offset, frame, you name it. It's still there. Why is it there anyway. Is it some kind a header that I could possibly undefine? Anyway, here is the code:

```
           List{
                
                ForEach(prim, id: \.id)  { value in
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                    HStack {
                        Text(value.label)
                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                            .padding(.vertical, 0)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width/4)
                        
                        Spacer(minLength: geometry.size.width/4)
                        
                        TextField("", value: value.data   , formatter: NumberFormatter())
                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                            .padding(.vertical, 0)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                            
                    }.padding(.top, 0)
                    }.padding(.top, 0)
                }.padding(.top, 0)
            }
            .padding(.top, 0)
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
```

[image]
I have not defined the grey area, so why is it there? It pushes my list down and so my third item in the list disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is not empty `NavigationView` (because it is not clear where is this List placed), then it is due to used list style.

You can use instead plain style

```
        }
        .padding(.top, 0)
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
```

Comment: you r a genius, I was ripping my hair out for that. But now it is clear I should have seen it - it's the "group" modifier that should have drawn my attention!!

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of that top/bottom padding while still using GroupedListStyle?

Answer (score 0):

Before `var body: some View` put this:

```
init()
{
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
}
```